# Can you configure QDebug to automatically output with text formatting, and insert info such as the datatypes or namespaces it is returning?

Tags: qt, debugging, qstring, qdebug

```
QString m_BoatProgramming("Boat Programming");
qDebug() << m_BoatProgramming;
qDebug() << QDate::currentDate();
```

Gives me:

```
"Boat Programming"
"Saturday 20th, 2016"
```

In some circumstances, rather than going through all the trouble of finding the terminal formatting codes, and manually putting in the metadata, I'd like it to output this:

**`QString`**`m_BoatProgramming``:`[`"Boat Programming"`](http://boatprogramming.com)
**`QDate::currentDate()`**`:`[`"Saturday 20th, 2016"`](http://boatprogramming.com)

Is this already possible, or do I need to derive a class from qDebug() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it'is possible with [message handler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler). Also it's allow you to write message to files of whatever you need.

Here is a modified example from doc to match your requirements:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <typeinfo>

#include <QDebug>

void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg)
{
    QByteArray localMsg = msg.toLocal8Bit();
    switch (type) {
    case QtDebugMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "Debug: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), context.file, context.line, context.function);
        break;
    case QtInfoMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "Info: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), context.file, context.line, context.function);
        break;
    case QtWarningMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), context.file, context.line, context.function);
        break;
    case QtCriticalMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "Critical: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), context.file, context.line, context.function);
        break;
    case QtFatalMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), context.file, context.line, context.function);
        abort();
    }
}

#define MY_DEBUG( exp ) qDebug() << typeid(exp).name() << #exp << exp

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageOutput);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QString str = "Shit happens!";
    MY_DEBUG( str );

    return 0;
}
```

Will output:

```
Debug: class QString str "Shit happens!" (..\ProjectorControl\ProjectorControl\main.cpp:56, int __cdecl main(int,char **))
```

I think with more macro magic or templates you can achieve more convient behaviour.

Note: Be carefull using this macro: in fact exp will be executed twice.

Comment: Should I just add a class to my qt project, and import, or toss this somewhere in one of my classes?

Comment: @Akiva Sorry didn't understand tour question. Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Where am I defining `void myMessageOutput` and `MY_DEBUG` ?

Comment: myMessageOutput and MY_DEBUG could be defined anywhere, and should be visible from where you are using it. qInstallMessageHandler accept pointer to a function. MY_DEBUG is just a macro.
Be carefull: exp in macro will be executed twice